# How to create and modify copy of data frame in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a quality control application in Shiny where I'd like to be able to keep an "original" or raw data file, and create another file with extra columns.  I'm running into a problem where I can't figure out how to do this without overwriting the original data frame.  My current code looks like this, which works fine, but again, destroys the original data frame.

```
        ##########################################################################################
    reactiveData <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
    
    #This function is responsible for loading in the selected file
    observe({
            req(input$file_selector)
            rv$df <- read.csv(paste0(parseDirPath(c(home = 'C:\\Users\\Ruben\\Desktop\\Test_QC_Program\\FiveMin'), file_dir()),'\\',input$file_selector),skip=1,na.strings='Null') # Simplified for testing
    })
    
    # This previews the CSV data file
    output$filetable <- renderDataTable({
            rv$df
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$qc_final_cols, {
            if (input$qc_final_cols){
                    utc <- ymd_hms(rv$df$TmStamp,tz='UTC')
                    ldt <- with_tz(utc,tzone='America/Chicago')
                    bv0 <- which(hour(ldt) == 0 & minute(ldt) == 0 & second(ldt) == 0)
                    if (length(bv0) > 0){
                            ldt[bv0] <- ldt[bv0] - 1}
                    
                    rv$df <- rv$df %>%
                            add_column(LDT = as.character(ldt), .after = 'TmStamp')
                    
                    for (v in 1:length(var_names)){
                            ind <- which(colnames(rv$df) == var_names[v])
                            rv$df <- rv$df %>% 
                                    add_column(z = NA,.after = ind)
                            colnames(rv$df)[ind+1] <- paste0(var_names[v],'_QC')
                            rv$df <- rv$df %>% 
                                    add_column(y = NA,.after = ind+1)
                            colnames(rv$df)[ind+2] <- paste0(var_names[v],'_Final')
                    }
            }
    })
    #######################################################################################
```

Is there a way to refer to the original data frame that I read in, as I try in the code below so I can create a new, separate data frame?  I want the new data frame to be reactive, not the original output$rawdata.

```
        output$rawdata <- renderDataTable({
            req(input$station_file)
            rawdata <- read.csv(input$station_file$datapath,
                                header = input$header,
                                skip = input$skip,
                                na.strings = input$nastrings)
    })
    
    qcdata <- reactiveValues(df = "rawdata")  ##RIGHT HERE I AM TRYING TO
REFER TO THE ORIGINALLY READ IN DATA, BUT UNSUCCESSFULLY
    
    observeEvent(input$station_file, {
                    utc <- ymd_hms(qcdata$df$TmStamp,tz='UTC')
                    ldt <- with_tz(utc,tzone='America/Chicago')
                    bv0 <- which(hour(ldt) == 0 & minute(ldt) == 0 & second(ldt) == 0)
                    if (length(bv0) > 0){
                            ldt[bv0] <- ldt[bv0] - 1}

                    qcdata$df <- qcdata$df %>%
                            add_column(LDT = as.character(ldt), .after = 'TmStamp')

                    for (v in 1:length(var_names)){
                            ind <- which(colnames(qcdata$df) == var_names[v])
                            qcdata$df <- qcdata$df %>%
                                    add_column(z = NA,.after = ind)
                            colnames(qcdata$df)[ind+1] <- paste0(var_names[v],'_QC')
                            qcdata$df <- qcdata$df %>%
                                    add_column(y = NA,.after = ind+1)
                            colnames(qcdata$df)[ind+2] <- paste0(var_names[v],'_Final')
                    }
    })

    # This previews the CSV data file
    output$qcdata <- renderDataTable({
            qcdata$df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read in your data, you can make a copy of it. It's not defined in your code above, but I assume that `rv` is also a `reactiveValues` object. Then you can do:

```
rv <- reactiveValues()
observe({
            req(input$file_selector)
            rv$original_data <- read.csv(paste0(parseDirPath(c(home = 'C:\\Users\\Ruben\\Desktop\\Test_QC_Program\\FiveMin'), file_dir()),'\\',input$file_selector),skip=1,na.strings='Null') # Simplified for testing
            rv$df <- rv$original_data
    })
```

Afterwards, you can do your calculations with `rv$df` but still have the original data.